# how do i get a css grid to break evently with offset sizes

Tags: css, responsive-design

first off i'm trying to accomplish this with CSS Grid.  Every tutorial or blog post is mainly about grid elements with the same width.

[image: this is what i'm wokring on.]

here's the code i have so far:  it works for desktop but they all just stay together with i have the

```
.grid-main {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 2fr 1fr 1fr;
}
@media(max-width: 990px) {
    .grid-main {
        grid-template-columns: 3fr 2fr 2fr;
    }
}
```

how do i get the first box to go full with and the last to wrap underneath at 50%?

thank you!

Answer (score 1):

For the tablet size, you’ll need a 2x2 grid, then on the first child element you’ll need a `grid-column` rule to specify that it must span two columns.

Note that when you run this snippet, you’ll need to use the **full page** link to see the responsiveness working properly.

```css
.grid-main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto; /* mobile-first design */
  gap: 5px;
}

/* tablet size */
@media (min-width: 750px) {
  .grid-main {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  }
  .grid-main>div:first-child {
    grid-column: 1 / span 2;
  }
}

/* desktop size */
@media (min-width: 1000px) {
  .grid-main {
    grid-template-columns: 3fr 2fr 2fr;
  }
  .grid-main>div:first-child {
    grid-column: auto;
  }
}

.grid-main>div {
  background: #eee;
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-main">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```